# Keep modal presentation in SplitViewController after collapsing/expanding

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I want to do it like in the contacts app on the iPhone 8 Plus model:

I can start editing and the edit view comes with a modal presentation:

[image: portrait]

After rotation it keeps the edit view controller open:

[image]

My problem is:

**After expanding/collapsing the split view, the edit view controller disappears and the unsaved changes are gone. How to keep the modally presented edit view controller open after rotation?**

Answer (score 0):

The object that is the delegate for your split view (that is, the object conforming to UISplitViewControllerDelegate) can provide the following function:

```
func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController,
                         collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController,
                         onto primaryViewController: UIViewController)
                        -> Bool
```

If you return "false" then the secondary view controller will remain on the screen (your "edit view controller"). If you return "true" then the primary view controller will be displayed.